# Why does my speech recognition work every other time in the vosk model?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, rabbitmq, fastapi

For practice , I decided to develop an api for loading a package of files in the format .zip. For me, it should have worked like this - a batch of files is loaded into fastapi and a message is sent to the queue. And in the micro service, a message is listened to and a function is executed that determines what kind of data is in the file package. For audio files, it must transcribe.

Next I will demonstrate the code.

Here are my classes for communicating with RabbitMQ

```
import pika 

class RabbitMQConsumer():
    def __init__(self, host, port, username, password, exchange_name, parameters, connect_name):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.exchange_name = exchange_name
        self.parameters = parameters
        self.connect_name = connect_name
        self.connection = None
        self.channel = None
    
    def connect(self):
        credentials = pika.PlainCredentials(self.username, self.password)
        parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters(
            host=self.host,
            port=self.port,
            virtual_host='/',
            credentials=credentials,
            #client_properties=self.connect_name#{'connection_name': 'MyConnectionName'}
        )
        self.connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
        self.channel = self.connection.channel()
        self.channel.exchange_declare(exchange=self.exchange_name, exchange_type='direct')
        result = self.channel.queue_declare('', exclusive=True)
        self.queue_name = result.method.queue
        for key in self.parameters.keys():
            self.channel.queue_bind(exchange=self.exchange_name, queue=self.queue_name, routing_key=key)
        self.channel.basic_consume(queue=self.queue_name, on_message_callback=self.callback, auto_ack=True)
    
    def callback(self, ch, method, properties, body):
        if method.routing_key in self.parameters:
            self.parameters[method.routing_key](body)
    
    def start_consuming(self):
        self.channel.start_consuming()
    
    def disconnect(self):
        self.connection.close()


import pika

class RabbitMQProducer():
    def __init__(self, host, port, username, password, exchange_name, routing_key):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.exchange_name = exchange_name
        self.routing_key = routing_key
        self.connection = None
        self.channel = None
    
    def connect(self):
        credentials = pika.PlainCredentials(self.username, self.password)
        parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters(self.host, self.port, '/', credentials)
        self.connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
        self.channel = self.connection.channel()
        self.channel.exchange_declare(exchange=self.exchange_name, exchange_type='direct')
    
    def send_message(self, message, routing_key):
        self.channel.basic_publish(
            exchange=self.exchange_name,
            routing_key=routing_key,
            body=message
        )
    
    def disconnect(self):
        self.connection.close()
```

Here is my endpoint with the api where the files are sent

```
class CaseUploaderController(Controller):
    prefix = "/api/upload_case"
    tags = ["upload case"]
    producer = RabbitMQProducer('localhost', 5672, 'rmquser', 'rmqpass', 'upload_case_procces', 'upload_process')

    @post("/upload_case")
    async def upload_case(self, password: str, file: UploadFile = File(...)):
        if password == "1":
            contents = await file.read()
            zip_data = BytesIO(contents)
            with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_data, 'r') as zip_ref:
                save_path = "C:\work_stuff\cases"
                extract_folder = os.path.join(save_path, file.filename.split(".")[0])
                os.makedirs(extract_folder, exist_ok=True)
                zip_ref.extractall(extract_folder)
            folder_path = os.path.abspath(extract_folder)
            body_json = json.dumps({"folder_path": folder_path})
            self.producer.connect()
            self.producer.send_message(body_json, 'upload_process')
            self.producer.disconnect()
            return JSONResponse(status_code=200, content={"folder_path": folder_path})
        else:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=403, detail="Wrong Password")
```

Here is a file from another microservice that listens to RabbitMQ after downloading .package zip

```
a = StartCaseProccess

parameters_upload_case = {
    'upload_process': a.get_file_paths,
    'audio_process': start_audio_process
}

def upload_case_consume():
    consumer = RabbitMQConsumer('localhost', 5672, 'rmquser', 
                                'rmqpass', 'upload_case_procces', parameters_upload_case, 
                                {'connection_name': 'Upload_Case_connection'})
    consumer.connect()
    consumer.start_consuming()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=upload_case_consume, args=())
    t1.start()
```

Here is a class and a function that scatters the contents of a zip package into different functions

```
class StartCaseProccess():
    producer = RabbitMQProducer('localhost', 5672, 'rmquser', 'rmqpass', 'upload_case_procces', 'upload_process')

    @classmethod
    def get_file_paths(self, folder_path):
        folder_path = json.loads(folder_path)["folder_path"]
        file_paths = []
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder_path):
            for file_name in files:
                file_path = os.path.join(root, file_name)
                #print(file_name)#file_path, file_name)
                if ".json" in file_name:
                    a = 2
                elif ".wav" in file_name:
                    #print(2)
                    body_json = json.dumps({"audio_path": file_path})
                    self.producer.connect()
                    self.producer.send_message(body_json, 'audio_process')
                    self.producer.disconnect()
                elif ".jpg" in file_name:
                    b = 4
```

And here is the same process for audio files

```
class AudioTranscriptionProcess():
    def __init__(self):
        self.model = Model("C:\work_stuff\server-proccess\\app\models\model-0.22")
        self.recognizer = KaldiRecognizer(self.model, 16000)
        self.audio_player = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        self.output_device_index = 0
        self.audio_reader = self.audio_player.open(
            format=pyaudio.paInt16, 
            channels=1,
            rate=32000,
            output=True,
            output_device_index=self.output_device_index,
            frames_per_buffer=32000
        )
    
    def audio_transcription_process(self, audio_file_path):
        with open(audio_file_path, "rb") as audio_file:
            while True:
                audio_data = audio_file.read(32000)
                if len(audio_data) == 0:
                    break
                if self.recognizer.AcceptWaveform(audio_data):
                    result = json.loads(self.recognizer.Result())
                    if 'text' in result:
                        yield result['text']

    def get_text_variable(self, audio_file_path):
        text_data = []
        for text in self.audio_transcription_process(audio_file_path):
            text_data.append(text)
        return text_data

audio_transcription_process = AudioTranscriptionProcess()

def start_audio_process(message):
    parse_message = json.loads(message)
    audio_path = parse_message["audio_path"]
    words_list = audio_transcription_process.get_text_variable(audio_path)
    print(audio_path, words_list)
```

If I use a class call directly to parse audio - Audio Transcription Process, then it always returns the text to me. And when I send messages via RabbitMQ, then every other time I get empty lists. I don't understand what this could be related to and how to fix it